# How to use jQuery UI Progress Bar to Show Image Load Completion

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-ui, load, progress-bar

I have a div tag with a ton of images in other divs, and possibley even within other divs, and so on. Is there any way that I can have a [jQuery UI Progressbar](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar)
show the completion of the images loaded? Background images are unimportant, but if you have a solution for both, then please feel free to tell me how to do this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/hkJhP/81/

We have to go through all  elements on the page, count them, and add a part which checks if image is finally loaded (beginning with new Image() part).

Then we have interval that checks how many images we have loaded so far. It runs every 1ms until all images are loaded. I'd add counter to stop it after 20 seconds or so.

loaded variable has to be fed to progressbar plugin.